# Can't display element although it loaded?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have problem is when i use ajax to send data to php server and get it to display in view, but data can't display in view although it loaded when i check in console. Please help me solved it.
This is my code :
**View and script**

```
<div class="col-xs-12" style="display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">
<h5 class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 control-label" style="">Vị trí：</h5>
<div id="positionDiv" class="col-sm-3">
    <select id="position" tabindex="9" name="recruitment[positions]" value="<?php echo $this->data['recruitment']->positions; ?>" data-none-selected-text class="selectpicker">
        <option style="display: none" selected disabled value=""></option>
        <?php foreach($this->data['position'] as $key => $value): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $value->positions ?>" <?php if ($this->data["recruitment"]->positions == $value->name): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>
                <?php echo $value->name; ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
    <input id="positionHidden" type="hidden">
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#position option").each(function(){
            $(this).siblings("[value='"+ this.value+"']").remove();
        });
        $('#market').on('change', function(event) {
            var value = $('#market').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: window.location.href,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    market: value
                },
                success: function(response){
                    var indexStart = response.indexOf('id="position"') - 8;
                    var indexEnd = response.indexOf('positionHidden') - 49;
                    var str = response.substring(indexStart,indexEnd).replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
                    $('#position').remove();
                    $('#positionDiv').append(str);
                    //document.getElementById('positionDiv').innerHTML = str;
                    console.log($('#positionDiv'));
                }
            });

        });
        $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
            options.async = true;
        });                
    });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
class CandidateController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct($route, $urlValue) {
        parent::__construct($route, $urlValue);   
    }

    public function initData() {
        $this->view->setData("resource", ResourceCompany::getAllResource());
        $this->view->setData("market", Market::getAllMarket());         
    }

    public function showPosition() {
        $market = $_POST['market'];
        isset($market) ? $market : null;

        $this->view->setData("position", Recruitment::getPositionByMarket($market));           
    }

    public function showTitle() {
        isset($market) ? $market : null;
        isset($position) ? $position : null;

        $this->view->setData("title", Recruitment::getTitleByMarketPosition($market, $position));
    }

    public function register() {
        $this->initData();    

        if (isset($_POST['market'])) {
            $this->showPosition();
        }
    }
   $this->view->output("menu");
}
```

Everything alright, data send and get is okay but it can't display in view although i can get it from console.log.

Comment: Could you share us your AJAX response?

Comment: my AJAX response is string with contents all of html elements of page

Answer (score 0):

mybe you have special characters in your content.
you most replace this characters before send in php code and reverse after get in javascript

"&" = & amp;

"\"" = & quot;

"'" = & apos;

"<" = & lt;

">" = & gt;

remove space after & plase

Comment: this is my `str` when i add to div tag: `<select id="position" tabindex="9" name="recruitment[positions]" value="" data-none-selected-text class="selectpicker"> <option style="display: none" selected disabled value=""></option> <option value="2" > PG </option> <option value="2" > PG </option> <option value="7" > SE </option> </select>`

Comment: in your content is special characters such as <," ,> .replace special characters in PHP code with equivalent code and when get string in ajax (client side)  replace all replaced characters with the original characters and then add your string to div content.